# OlMailRecipientType always starts off as OlTo even when I set it to something else

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Excel VBA function that I'm using to create emails, address them, attach files, etc. It works, mostly, but for reasons beyond my fathoming, it always assigns recipients the olTo type when they're created, and even if I change the OlMailRecipientType property, the recipient remains in the To box. It DOES update that recipient's type, and move them to the correct box (CC, BCC), when I add another recipient though. In other words, so as long as I fill out the To (default type) recipients last, things sort themselves out in the end, but...I wish I understood this issue and didn't have to just ignore it. Functions are as follows:

```
Function Email_Item(Optional ByVal EI As Outlook.MailItem, Optional ByVal RecipientCodes As String, _
    **Optional ByVal RecipientType As Outlook.OlMailRecipientType = olTo**, _
    Optional ByVal Attach1 As Workbook, Optional ByVal Attach2 As Workbook, _
    Optional ByVal Attach3 As Workbook, Optional ByVal Attach4 As Workbook) As Outlook.MailItem

Dim Email_Attachments As Outlook.Attachments

If Not EI Is Nothing Then
    Set Email_Item = EI
Else
    Dim Outlook_Connector As Outlook.Application
    Set Outlook_Connector = OutlookApp()
    Set Email_Item = Outlook_Connector.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Email_Item.Display
    If Not Outlook_Connector.Session.Accounts("email@website.net") Is Nothing Then
        Email_Item.SendUsingAccount = Outlook_Connector.Session.Accounts("email@website.net")
    Else
        Email_Item.SentOnBehalfOfName = "email@website.net"
    End If
End If

Set Email_Attachments = Email_Item.Attachments

If Not Attach1 Is Nothing Then Email_Attachments.Add Attach1.FullName
If Not Attach2 Is Nothing Then Email_Attachments.Add Attach2.FullName
If Not Attach3 Is Nothing Then Email_Attachments.Add Attach3.FullName
If Not Attach4 Is Nothing Then Email_Attachments.Add Attach4.FullName

Dim Distribution As Outlook.Recipient

Dim L As Integer

For L = 1 To Len(RecipientCodes)
    If Mid(RecipientCodes, L, 1) = "C" Then 'Self
        **Add_Recipient Email_Item, RecipientType, "Reporting"**
        GoTo NextIter
    End If
'...more directory if statements...
NextIter:
Next

End Function

Function Add_Recipient(ByVal Email_Item As Outlook.MailItem, ByVal RecipientType As Outlook.OlMailRecipientType, ParamArray Email_Recipient() As Variant) As Outlook.Recipient

'Note that CC/BCC recipients are added first; To recipients must come last.

Dim Recip As Variant

For Each Recip In Email_Recipient
    Set Add_Recipient = Email_Item.Recipients.Add(CStr(Recip))
    **Add_Recipient.Type = RecipientType**
Next Recip

Set Add_Recipient = Nothing
```

To rephrase my problem, if I call Email_Item like this, I get two addresses in the To box:

```
Dim EI As Outlook.MailItem
Set EI = Email_Item(EI, "C")
Set EI = Email_Item(, "RSM", olBCC)
End Sub
```

Swapping the two Set EI lines results works, however, because although it sets every recipient as olTo at first, adding a new recipient updates the position of the previous recipient. I assumed I had to put the "Add_Recipient.Type = RecipientType" line before the "Set Add_Recipient = Email_Item.Recipients.Add(CStr(Recip))" line, but the Add_Recipient object has to be created before that works.

I have the following add-ins:

- Visual Basic for Applications
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Scripting Runtime
- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library
- Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft OLE DB Service Component 1.0 Type Library

Anyone know what this is doing? (Also should I kick VBA to the curb and start using C# for reporting automation?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to re-add recipients in the loop:

```
For Each Recip In Email_Recipient
    Set Add_Recipient = Email_Item.Recipients.Add(CStr(Recip))
    **Add_Recipient.Type = RecipientType**
Next Recip
```

Instead, you need to get the `Recipients` collection in the function and then call the `Add` method which creates a new recipient in the Recipients collection. The name of the recipient can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient. For example:

```
Sub CreateStatusReportToBoss() 

    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 

    Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
    Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev")
    myRecipient.Type = OlMailRecipientType.olCC  
    myItem.Subject = "Status Report" 
    myItem.Display 

End Sub
```

You may also want to call the [Recipients.ResolveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Recipients.ResolveAll) method after which attempts to resolve all the Recipient objects in the Recipients collection against the Address Book.

Read more about that in the article that I wrote for the technical blog - [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/).

Comment: Given that you wrote some of the articles I used to create my Outlook automation, I'm going to go ahead and mark this as correct. I personally fixed my problem by switching jobs (and code languages), but hopefully this helps someone else.